# Javafx Toolkit initialisation on Font loading

Tags: java, maven, javafx, javafx-8

I created a simple test for loading JavaFX font:

```
public class JavaFXFontTest {
    @Test
    public void testDirectDefaultFontInitialisation() {
        Font font = Font.getDefault();

        assertNotNull(font);
    }
    @Test
    public void testTextWithLoadedFont() {
        String defaultFont = "/fonts/starnberg.ttf";
        Font font = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream(defaultFont), 12);

        Text text = new Text();
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setText("42");

        assertNotNull(font);
    }
}
```

This test runs without a problem on Linux and in the IDE on Windows. However when I want to run it in my Maven build I run into the Problem where is says `Internal graphics not initialized yet`. This is usually the case if the code makes a call to `Toolkit.getToolkit()`.

Tracking down the stacktrace I have come to this method in `PrismFontFactory`:

```
   public static float getSystemFontSize() {
        if (systemFontSize == -1) {
            if (isWindows) {
                float uiScale = Screen.getMainScreen().getUIScale();
                systemFontSize = getSystemFontSizeNative() / uiScale;
            } else if (isMacOSX || isIOS) {
                systemFontSize = MacFontFinder.getSystemFontSize();
            } else if (isAndroid) {
               systemFontSize = AndroidFontFinder.getSystemFontSize();
            } else if (isEmbedded) {
                try {
                    int screenDPI = Screen.getMainScreen().getResolutionY();
                    systemFontSize = ((float) screenDPI) / 6f; // 12 points
                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                    // if no screen is defined
                    systemFontSize = 13f; // same as desktop Linux
                }
            } else {
                systemFontSize = 13f; // Gnome uses 13.
            }
        }
        return systemFontSize;
    }
```

This explains that why it works on Linux as there are environment specific cases in there. I am not quite clear why it does work on Windows from the IDE (IntelliJ), but I suspect, that the Toolkit was initialized beforehand and the test run does not run in a forked JVM.
How can I solve the problem, so the Maven build runs everywhere, preferable also in a headless environment?

I could [force the Toolkit to become initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805488/fake-javafx-platform-start), but that requires relying on internal API and that will get me in trouble latest with JDK 9 (Jigsaw).